# ILT0005 Gatekeeper exe exit code- 532462766

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

[image]

Hello Guys,

I am trying to deploy my Xamarin UWP app on mobile in release mode with ARM but it’s giving some issue in deployment. I am sending you screen sort. Please check the attached file and give some solution and suggestion so that I can solve these issue.

Thanks,

Comment: I think that is a problem with resource file.

Comment: What will i do to remove this? Can you give me some suggestion or option to remove this issue

Comment: Is there same issue in Debug model ?

Comment: No it was not giving issue in debug mode and thanks for your reply. Now my issue has been solved

Comment: Can you share more details on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Due to some namespace mismatching. I was facing this issue...